# Every finite-dimensional vector space has a change-of-coordinate matrix (transition matrix) of negative determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Actually I asked the question in an attempt to know what orientation on manifolds is about. Without further ado, let me introduce the question in a more explicit way. Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space and let $I_V$ denote the identity operator on $V$. I would like to know if there exist ordered bases $\beta,\gamma$ for $V$ such that the representation $[I_V]_\beta^\gamma$ of $I_V$ in $\beta,\gamma$, also known as the **change-of-coordinate matrix** from $\beta$ to $\gamma$, has **negative** determinant $\det([I_V]_\beta^\gamma)$.

I think the answer is positive, and my reasoning is rather straightforward. Let $\beta=\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ be an ordered basis for $V$. Then it is easy to see that $\gamma=\{-u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ is another ordered basis for $V$ ($\gamma$ is a spanning set for $V$ and still linearly independent). Now let us calculate the determinant of $[I_V]_\beta^\gamma$. We obtain
$$\det([I_V]_\beta^\gamma)=\det(\mathsf{diag}(-1,1,\ldots,1))=-1<0.$$
Is there any fallacy in my reasoning? Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is good. Also, every matrix with nonzero determinant takes a basis to another basis. So if you start with $\beta=\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$ like you have and then take $M$ to be literally any matrix with negative determinant, it is the change of coordinate matrix from $\beta$ to $\{Mu_1,\dots,Mu_n\}$. So there isn't just one. There's...a lot!

Comment: Seems good, except if $\dim V =0$.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.